# Declare array of lambdas in Java

Tags: java, lambda

I'd like to create an array of lambda. The problem is that the lambda could be different from each other. Example:

```
private interface I0 {
    int interface0(int a, int b);
}

private interface I1 {
    int interface1(double d);
}
```

Now, how can I declare a list which can contain both I0 and I1?

```
List<Object> test = Arrays.asList(
        (int a, int b) -> a + b,
        (double d) -> d * 2
);
```

Obviously `Object` does not work.

Comment: Can you please explain us your use case? I think this has a bad smell.

Comment: Each interface should "map" the parameters of a function. I'd like to generate each parameter based on some criteria.

Comment: is it OK if you change your methods definition to be the same? For example `double interface1(double d, double amount /* instead of 2 - pass some amount*/);`?

Comment: Why does "Object" not work? It's the only thing those two interfaces share in common!

Comment: @TimB Probably because there is no unique interface the lambda maps to. At least, the code is lacking an explicit cast.

Comment: @Surcle The question is: What do you intend to do with that list? How do you determine if you are trying to call with one or with two arguments?

Answer (score 21):

You must assign the lambda expressions to variables of the functional interface types first.

Otherwise the compiler cannot infer the types of these lambda expressions.

```
I0 i0 = (int a, int b) -> a + b;
I1 i1 = (double d) -> (int) (d * 2);
List<Object> test = Arrays.asList(
    i0,
    i1
);
```

That said, I'm not sure what's the point of storing these lambda expressions in a `List<Object>`. You can't use them without casting them back to the individual functional interface types.

Comment: just a little (side?)note: probably better use `(int) (d * 2)` that is, cast the result of the multiplication, not just `d`

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger good point. I only added the cast so that the lambda expression matches the `I1` interface, and didn't care about the specifics (assuming this is probably just an example and not the actual lambda expression the OP is going to use).

Answer (score 14):

You could cast to the respective Interface like:

```
List<Object> test = Arrays.asList(
    (I0) (int a, int b) -> a + b,
    (I1) (double d) -> (int) (d * 2)
);
```

despite this being shorter, I would also consider [Eran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47650202/85421) maybe it is more readable and easier to understand (if having more functions). And I also can't see the use case for such a construct...

It gets even shorter (not necessarily better):

```
List<Object> test = Arrays.asList(
    (I0) (a, b) -> a + b,
    (I1) d -> (int) (d * 2)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I gather, you're trying to do something like this:

```
public static void main(String... args){
    List<Object> lambdas = Arrays.asList(
            (IntBinaryOperator) (int a, int b) -> a + b,
            (DoubleToIntFunction) (double d) -> (int)(d * 2)
    );
    for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++){
        // Apply lambdas.get(i) to args[i]
    }
}
```

That comment is a pretty big deal, though; how would you implement it?

You could check the type during each round:

```
    for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++){
        if(lambdas.get(i) instanceof IntBinaryOperator){
            processedArgs[i] =
                    ((IntBinaryOperator) lambdas.get(i)).applyAsInt(MAGIC_NUMBER, Integer.parseInt(args[i]));
        }else{
            // All your other cases (may take a while)
        }
    }
```

Validating each possible type is a huge pain, and if it's position-dependent, it's only going to run once anyway, so it's overkill.

My recommendation depends on if this is going to be static (your code runs only on one specific set of arguments ever) or dynamic (it needs to run on all kinds of arguments).  For static code, I'd just apply the lambdas without a loop:

```
public static void main(String... args){
    processedArgs = new int[args.length];
    IntBinaryOperator op1 = (int a, int b) -> a + b;
    DoubleToIntFunction op2 =  (double d) -> (int)(d * 2);

    processedArgs[0] = op1.applyAsInt(MAGIC_NUMBER, Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
    processedArgs[1] = op2.applyAsInt(Double.parseDouble(args[1]));
}
```

For a dynamic solution, I'd recommend switching to a single functional interface.  I would go with the maximum requirement and fill in dummy values where not needed:

```
public static void main(String... args){
    processedArgs = new int[args.length];
    List<DoubleBinaryOperator> ops = Arrays.asList(
            (a, b) -> a + b,
            (d, ignore) -> (d * 2)
    );
    for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++){
        processedArgs[i] = (int)ops.get(i).applyAsDouble(Double.parseDouble(args[i]), MAGIC_NUMBER);
    }
}
```

Or, preferably, if you can simplify your lambdas:

```
public static void main(String... args){
    processedArgs = new int[args.length];
    List<DoubleToIntFunction> ops = Arrays.asList(
            (d) -> (int)(d + MAGIC_NUMBER),
            (d) -> (int)(d * 2)
    );
    for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++){
        processedArgs[i] = ops.get(i).applyAsInt(Double.parseDouble(args[i]));
    }
}
```

I feel like your solution ultimately is less complicated than any of these.  Just trying to help point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your interfaces use vararg typing:

```
public class NaryFunctionTest {

    interface NaryFunction<R extends Number> {
        R run(R... args);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        NaryFunction<Integer> f1 = (Integer[] o) -> o[0] + o[1];
        NaryFunction<Double> f2 = (Double[] o) -> o[0] *2;
        List<NaryFunction<?>> test = Arrays.asList(
            f1,
            f2
        );
    }
}
```