# Using a DoubleUnaryOperator vs Function<Double, Double>

Tags: java, functional-programming

I have been using basic functional interfaces for a recent java project. I have a problem; I want to be able to store a number of functions (all Function<Double, Double>) in an array. I know I can't do this as it violates type safety, however I CAN store DoubleUnaryOperator (another type of lambda) in an array.

After reading the documentation I'm still a little unclear on the differences between using a Function<Double, Double> and a DoubleUnaryOperator. Would it be problematic to store DoubleUnaryOperators in this way?

Comment: Take a look at this very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47650162/declare-array-of-lambdas-in-java

Comment: If all your functions are supposedly working on primitive `double`, there is no harm in representing them as `DoubleUnaryOperator` or else you would suffer the cost of boxing cost and `null` values would have no more meaning.

Comment: Of course, you can always create a `List<Function<Double,Double>>` if it suits your purpose.